# javascript plain object: what happen to this property?

Tags: javascript, html, object

Look at myGameArea object; I understand that canvas is a **property**. But what happend when I call the start() method? that property seems to have to properties now, width and height. so the canvas property is lost? is an object?. Can someone explain that? Thanks

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: (OT) "what happen?" - "all your base are belong to us!"

Comment: `canvas` is an object (of the type "DOM element"). An object can have its own properties. It's basic OOP theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is `myGameArea` and `canvas` is a property of it.

The canvas property is not lost. It's there, accessible by using `this.canvas` from within `start()`, as you properly did. The `canvas` property also has it's own properties now, `width` and `height`.

You can view the `console.log` output in this example to verify:

https://jsfiddle.net/dfq4Lnho/

In order to do this without using `start`:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dfq4Lnho/1/

var myGameArea = function() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
}

myGameArea.prototype.somethingElse = function() {
    console.log('this is a method of myGameArea');
    console.log(this.canvas); // access this.canvas here too!
}

var tmp = new myGameArea();
console.log(tmp.canvas);
tmp.somethingElse();
```

Comment: I would remove the *now* since HTMLCanvasElement does have `width`and `height` properties by default.

Comment: interesing. but here a thing... How do you do the same thing without a method start()?... I mean adding properties to a property of plain object?

Comment: See updated response.